# Why I can't open mysql connection string?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.64;port=3307;Database=mifos;User ID=root;Password=admin;")
    Dim sql As String = "select c.customer_id,c.display_name, o.display_name as Office, (select p.display_name from personnel p where p.personnel_id=c.loan_officer_id) as Loan_officer,c.global_cust_num,c.date_of_birth,if (cd.gender=49,'male','female') as gender,government_id,(select qgr.response from question_group_response qgr,question_group_instance qgi  where  qgr.question_group_instance_id = qgi.id and qgi.entity_id=c.customer_id and qgr.sections_questions_id=3 and qgi.version_id= (select max(qgi.version_id) from question_group_instance qgi where qgi.entity_id=c.customer_id)) as mother_name, (select qgr.response from question_group_response qgr,question_group_instance qgi  where qgr.question_group_instance_id = qgi.id and qgi.entity_id=c.customer_id and qgr.sections_questions_id=4 and qgi.version_id= (select max(qgi.version_id) from question_group_instance qgi where qgi.entity_id=c.customer_id)) as display_name_eng  from customer c,office o,customer_detail cd  where(o.office_id = c.branch_id) and cd.customer_id=c.customer_id and c.branch_id=2"
    connection.Open("")
    sCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
    sAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "form")
    sTable = sDs.Tables("form")
    connection.Close()
    GridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("form")
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

*/

can't run  Mysql query in visual studio 2010 query builder 
and when i put query in behind code i get

> Error 1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Open'
>   accepts this number of arguments.

What's wrong with this query does query builder dosnt accept subquery ?

Comment: Is it for vb.net or asp.net? Please remove the inappropriate tag.

Comment: If you read your error message carefully a few times, you wouldn't need to ask a question. These messages are for you.

Answer (score 4):

You should write    `connection.Open()` instead of    `connection.Open(""`)

Answer (score 1):

Plz change  `connection.Open("")` to `connection.Open()`

[SqlConnection.Open Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)